# its seem python 'list.pop()' not work as it should

Tags: python, list

I have a really strange bug in my code.
I tried to create a code that will create random shift for me and my team, there is 5 shifts in 5 days and everyone should be in different shift each day.

The code its little big so i will try to pass only the relevant pieces here, but feel free to ask for more info and I will try to clarify.

```
from random import randint
shifts = [4, 4.2, 5, 6, 7]
days_names = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday']
workers_names = ['Itai', 'Or', 'Reut', 'Kuka', 'Aviel']


class Day(object):
    #create empty shift : worker list
    def __init__(self,shift,name):
        self.shift_list = {  x:'' for x in shift}
        self.name = name


    # create a list of workers that not work this day and choose
    # choose a random worker in 'worker_chosen' function  
    def shift_arrenge(self):
        self.today_workers = [x for x in workers_names if (x not in self.shift_list.values())]
        for shift, worker in self.shift_list.items():
            if not worker:
                self.shift_list[shift] = worker_chosen(shift,self.today_workers,self.name)
        print (self.shift_list)

 def worker_chosen(shift,WORKERS,day_name):
    worker_chosen =''
    print("today_workers")
    print(WORKERS)
    while(WORKERS):
        worker_chosen = WORKERS.pop(randint(0, len(WORKERS)-1))
        print("worker chosen: "+ worker_chosen)
        #check if the worker got this shift already if not update on the worker and return it
        if not (workers[worker_chosen].shift_list[shift]): 
            workers[worker_chosen].update(shift,day_name)
            break


    return worker_chosen
```

Now the bug is around `worker_chosen = WORKERS.pop(randint(0, len(WORKERS)-1))` line.
If the chosen worker shift is already taken and the program choose anther worker, in the next time that my `shift_arrenge` function call worker_chosen. the worker that didn't get choosen stile miss out from my WORKERS list. its like the pop remove him entirely.

here is example of my debugging output:

```
today_workers
['Itai', 'Or', 'Reut', 'Kuka', 'Aviel']
worker chosen: Or
worker Or didn't got choose..
worker chosen: Reut
worker Reut didn't got choose..
worker chosen: Kuka
worker Kuka got choose!
#now move to the next shift..
today_workers
['Itai', 'Aviel'] # but only kuka got choose!
```

Comment: When in doubt, blame Python's `list.pop()`? I think we can assume the problem lies elsewhere. :-)

Comment: Where is the code that prints `worker <name> didn't get choose..`?

Comment: i remove this line here. if the if code don't get execute the code coem to the line `print("worker " + worker_chosen+ " didn't got choose..")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *always* removing elements from the list. If any one of them should *not* be choosen, add them back on to the list, or do not remove them until they are actually choosen.

Note that `WORKERS` is manipulated *in place*; the list object itself is altered, not a copy. If you meant to manipulate a copy, then first create a shallow copy with:

```
WORKERS = list(WORKERS)
```

or

```
WORKERS = WORKERS[:]
```

otherwise the caller of your function will see the changes made; `self.today_workers` is still a reference to that same list.

Comment: really? its edit the starting list? but why? I just pass this list to WORKER, its not create a **local** list inside the function?

Comment: No, it creates a local **reference** inside the function. The value itself is not copied, and because it is mutable, any other reference to the same value will see the changes.

Comment: Ho, so its not work with string because its not mutable? thanks, first time that I see something like that.

Comment: Indeed, when handling strings, integers, etc. you create a new object with every operation, and rebind the local name to the new value.